# Why isn't my html style only applying to the body even though I am using block content?

Tags: html, css, django

So I am attempting to add a style for the body of my page but unfortunately it is applying to my navbar too which is coming from my base.html. What am I doing wrong here that it's applying to my navbar too? I only want it to apply the contents in `<body>`

messages.html

```
{% extends "dating_app/base.html" %}

{% load bootstrap4 %}

{% load static %}


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
{% block content %}
<style>
    body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 800px;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.container {
  border: 2px solid #dedede;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.darker {
  border-color: #ccc;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.container::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

.container img {
  float: left;
  max-width: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-right: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.container img.right {
  float: right;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right:0;
}

.time-right {
  float: right;
  color: #aaa;
}

.time-left {
  float: left;
  color: #999;
}

</style>



<body>

<a href="{% url 'dating_app:message' other_user.id %}">Start messaging!</a>

<h2>Chat Messages</h2>


{% for message in messages %}

    {% if message.sender_id == request.user.id %}
    <div class="container">
          <img src="{{  profile.photo.url  }}" alt="Avatar" style="width:100%;">
          <p>{{ message.message }}</p>
          <span class="time-right">{{ message.date }}</span>
    </div>

    {% elif message.sender_id == other_user.id %}
    <div class="container">
          <img src="/w3images/bandmember.jpg" alt="Avatar" class="right" style="width:100%;">
          <p>{{ message.message }}</p>
          <span class="time-left">{{ message.date }}</span>
    </div>

    {% endif %}
        <!--
        {% if message.sender_id == request.user.id %}
        <li class="text-right list-group-item"> {{ message.message }}<br>{{ message.date }} </li>
        {% elif message.sender_id == other_user.id %}
        <li class="text-left list-group-item"> {{ message.message }}<br>{{ message.date }} </li>

        {% endif %}
        -->


{%endfor %}
</body>








{% endblock content %}

</html>
```

**base.html**

```
{% load bootstrap4 %}
{% load static %}



{% load unread_messages_counter %}





<!-- Navbar is located in this file -->


<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/all.js"></script>


    {% block head %}
    <title>Base</title>
    {% endblock %}

    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="{% static  'css/notification.css' %}" type="text/css" class = "notification"/>

<style>





</style>
</head>
<body>


    <!-- Navigation -->
      <nav class="navbar navbar-custom navbar-expand-md    ">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class= 'navbar-brand'  href="{% url 'dating_app:home' %}"><img src="{% static 'images/cupids_corner_logo.jpg' %}"><h5 style="color:red"></h5> </a>
        <button class= "navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" 
        data-target="#navbarResponsive">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div  class="collapse navbar-collapse"  >
          <ul class ="navbar-nav ml-auto" >


            {% if user.is_authenticated %}


                {% unread_messages request.user as user_unread_messages %}
                {% if user_unread_messages > 0 %}


                    <li class="nav-item"  >
                        <a class=  "notification" style="color:brown" href="{% url 'dating_app:conversations' user.id %}" type="text/css" > 
                        <span>Inbox</span>
                        <span class="badge">{% unread_messages request.user %}</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>

                {% else %}

                    <li class="nav-item">

                        <a style="color:brown"  href="{% url 'dating_app:conversations' user.id %}">    
                            <span>Inbox</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                {% endif %}






                  <li class="nav-item">
                        <a style="color:brown"  href="{% url 'dating_app:view_matches' user.id %}">Matches</a>
                  </li>

                   <li class="nav-item">
                        <a style="color:brown"  href="{% url 'dating_app:mingle' %}">Mingle</a>
                   </li>

                   <li class="nav-item">
                        <a style="color:brown" href="{% url 'dating_app:profile' user.id %}">My Profile</a>
                   </li>

                   <li class="nav-item">
                        <a style="color:brown" href="{% url 'dating_app:logout' %}">log out</a>
                   </li>






            {% else %}

                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a style="color:brown" href="{% url 'dating_app:login' %}">login</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a style="color:brown" href="{% url 'dating_app:register' %}">register</a>
                </li>

            {% endif %}
          </ul>
        </div>
     <div>

    </nav>

    </div>



<!-- HEADER END -->


<!--Below is individual page will html will be rendered -->

{% block content %}

{% endblock %}

<hr class="my-4">

<!--Connect -->
<div class="container-fluid padding">
<div class="row text-center padding">
     <div class="col-12">
        <h2>Connect</h2>
     </div>
     <div class="col-12 social padding">
        <a href="http://www.facebook.com/"><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i></a>
        <a href="http://www.twitter.com/"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
        <a href="http://www.instagram.com/"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
        <a href="http://www.google.com/"><i class="fab fa-google-plus-g"></i></a>
        <a href="http://www.youtube.com/"><i class="fab fa-youtube"></i></a>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<!-- FOOTER AREA BEGINS BELOW-->

<footer>
<div class="container-fluid padding">
<div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <img src="{% static 'images/cupids_corner_logo.jpg' %}">
        <hr class="light">
        <p>703-309-9572</p>
        <p>rezazandirz@gmail.com</p>
        <p>100 Street Name</p>
        <p>City, State, 000</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <hr class="light">
        <h5>Our hours</h5>
        <hr class="light">
        <p>Monday: 9am-5pm</p>
        <p>Saturday: 10am-4pm</p>
        <p>Sunday: closed(like Chick-fil-A)</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <hr class="light">
        <h5>Our satellite offices</h5>
        <hr class="light">
        <p>City, State, 00000</p>
        <p>City, State, 00000</p>
        <p>City, State, 00000</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12">
        <hr class="light-100">
        <h5>&copy;CupidsCorner.com</h5>
    </div>


</footer>

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
      ================================================== -->
      <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->

      <script src="../../assets/js/vendor/popper.min.js"></script>
      <script src="../../dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Show us your base.html as well

Comment: @BiploveLamichhane Thx for letting me know, just put it up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets correct base.html

```
{% load bootstrap4 %}
{% load static %}

{% load unread_messages_counter %}

<!-- Navbar is located in this file -->


<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/all.js"></script>


    {% block head %}
    <title>Base</title>
    {% endblock %}

    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="{% static  'css/notification.css' %}" type="text/css" class = "notification"/>
    <style>
    <!-- Add this tag -->
    {% block styles %}

    {% endblock %}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Navigation -->
      <nav class="navbar navbar-custom navbar-expand-md">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class= 'navbar-brand'  href="{% url 'dating_app:home' %}"><img src="{% static 'images/cupids_corner_logo.jpg' %}"><h5 style="color:red"></h5> </a>
        <button class= "navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" 
        data-target="#navbarResponsive">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div  class="collapse navbar-collapse"  >
          <ul class ="navbar-nav ml-auto" >


            {% if user.is_authenticated %}


                {% unread_messages request.user as user_unread_messages %}
                {% if user_unread_messages > 0 %}


                    <li class="nav-item"  >
                        <a class=  "notification" style="color:brown" href="{% url 'dating_app:conversations' user.id %}" type="text/css" > 
                        <span>Inbox</span>
                        <span class="badge">{% unread_messages request.user %}</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>

                {% else %}

                    <li class="nav-item">

                        <a style="color:brown"  href="{% url 'dating_app:conversations' user.id %}">    
                            <span>Inbox</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                {% endif %}

                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a style="color:brown"  href="{% url 'dating_app:view_matches' user.id %}">Matches</a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a style="color:brown"  href="{% url 'dating_app:mingle' %}">Mingle</a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a style="color:brown" href="{% url 'dating_app:profile' user.id %}">My Profile</a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a style="color:brown" href="{% url 'dating_app:logout' %}">log out</a>
                </li>
            {% else %}

                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a style="color:brown" href="{% url 'dating_app:login' %}">login</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a style="color:brown" href="{% url 'dating_app:register' %}">register</a>
                </li>

            {% endif %}
          </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    </nav>

<!-- HEADER END -->


<!--Below is individual page will html will be rendered -->

{% block content %}

{% endblock %}

<hr class="my-4">

<!--Connect -->
<div class="container-fluid padding">
<div class="row text-center padding">
     <div class="col-12">
        <h2>Connect</h2>
     </div>
     <div class="col-12 social padding">
        <a href="http://www.facebook.com/"><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i></a>
        <a href="http://www.twitter.com/"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
        <a href="http://www.instagram.com/"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
        <a href="http://www.google.com/"><i class="fab fa-google-plus-g"></i></a>
        <a href="http://www.youtube.com/"><i class="fab fa-youtube"></i></a>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<!-- FOOTER AREA BEGINS BELOW-->

<footer>
<div class="container-fluid padding">
<div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <img src="{% static 'images/cupids_corner_logo.jpg' %}">
        <hr class="light">
        <p>703-309-9572</p>
        <p>rezazandirz@gmail.com</p>
        <p>100 Street Name</p>
        <p>City, State, 000</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <hr class="light">
        <h5>Our hours</h5>
        <hr class="light">
        <p>Monday: 9am-5pm</p>
        <p>Saturday: 10am-4pm</p>
        <p>Sunday: closed(like Chick-fil-A)</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <hr class="light">
        <h5>Our satellite offices</h5>
        <hr class="light">
        <p>City, State, 00000</p>
        <p>City, State, 00000</p>
        <p>City, State, 00000</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12">
        <hr class="light-100">
        <h5>&copy;CupidsCorner.com</h5>
    </div>


</footer>

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
      ================================================== -->
      <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->

      <script src="../../assets/js/vendor/popper.min.js"></script>
      <script src="../../dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Now, messages.html:

````
{% extends "dating_app/base.html" %}

{% load bootstrap4 %}

{% load static %}

{% block head %}
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title></title>
{% endblock %}

{% block styles %}
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 800px;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.container {
  border: 2px solid #dedede;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.darker {
  border-color: #ccc;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.container::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

.container img {
  float: left;
  max-width: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-right: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.container img.right {
  float: right;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right:0;
}

.time-right {
  float: right;
  color: #aaa;
}

.time-left {
  float: left;
  color: #999;
}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

    <a href="{% url 'dating_app:message' other_user.id %}">Start messaging!</a>

    <h2>Chat Messages</h2>
    {% for message in messages %}

        {% if message.sender_id == request.user.id %}
        <div class="container">
            <img src="{{  profile.photo.url  }}" alt="Avatar" style="width:100%;">
            <p>{{ message.message }}</p>
            <span class="time-right">{{ message.date }}</span>
        </div>

        {% elif message.sender_id == other_user.id %}
        <div class="container">
            <img src="/w3images/bandmember.jpg" alt="Avatar" class="right" style="width:100%;">
            <p>{{ message.message }}</p>
            <span class="time-left">{{ message.date }}</span>
        </div>

        {% endif %}
            <!--
            {% if message.sender_id == request.user.id %}
            <li class="text-right list-group-item"> {{ message.message }}<br>{{ message.date }} </li>
            {% elif message.sender_id == other_user.id %}
            <li class="text-left list-group-item"> {{ message.message }}<br>{{ message.date }} </li>

            {% endif %}
            -->

    {%endfor %}
{% endblock content %}

I have added styles block to add styles. And there was extra ```</div>```. Please check.
````